Cumulative GROUP BY Big Query
I really have a tough time trying to solve this in BQ so I would appreciate some help, thanks if you take the time to leave a comment. Let's suppose I have the "BASE" in Big Query, if I GROUP BY MONTH and COUNT(DISTINCT ID_CLIENT) I would get the "TABLE 1" but I would like to get somenthing like the "TABLE 2". That the first row has the number of unique clients in month 1 and the second row has the unique clientes in the month 1 and 2.
I don't know if I can achieve something like this using only the GROUP BY or I have to create another column in table "BASE" to GROUP BY that new variable or there is a way that I can achive this without creating a new column.


consider below approach
select months, (
    select count(distinct id)
    from unnest(split(id_clients)) id
  ) as count_distinct_clients
from (
  select 
    string_agg('' || month, ' AND ') over win as months,
    string_agg(id_clients) over win as id_clients
  from (
    select month, string_agg(distinct '' || id_client) as id_clients
    from base
    group by month
  )
  window win as (order by month range between unbounded preceding and current row)
) t
order by months

if applied to sample data in your question - output is


Thanks for your response Mikhail. Just a quick question if i want to do these but let´s say i have another column in the table "BASE" named "PROFILE" and the values that can take is "1" or "2" and i want just the same output but that you just give me but for profile "1" and "2". Could it be done with this approach?
